# Gitlab pipeline rules: how to not run a job when a branch has an open merge request? Preventing duplicate pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a project with two pipelines:

1. Run pipeline A for a push to a branch that has NO open merge request (smoke test run)
2. Run pipeline B for a push to a branch that does have an open merge request (full test run)

But I keep getting duplicate pipelines when a merge request is open, both job A and B run when I push a branch with an open merge request

I've read gitlab's documentation and concluded I have these options for configuring pipeline A to NOT run when a merge request is open:

```
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"'
```

or

```
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    when: never
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

But on both cases next to pipeline B, also this pipeline A is triggered even though I configure it should not run on a merge_request_event.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? It seems like a standard way of doing it so should not be difficult

Answer (score 2):

Actually this specific use case is [described in the official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines). Here's the workflow:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    # always run MR pipeline
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    # if it's a branch pipeline but there's an open MR on the source branch, don't run anything
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    # if it's a branch pipeline and there's no open MR, run the branch pipeline
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

With this workflow, when you push to a branch that doesn't have an open MR, normal branch pipeline is executed; and when you push to a branch that does have an open MR, the branch pipeline is suppressed/skipped, and only the MR pipeline is executed.

The relevant [predefined CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) are:

- `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is present in branch pipelines, but not in MR pipelines
- `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is set to `merge_request_event` for MR pipelines, but not for branch pipelines (where it would typically be set to `push`, but could be set to something else, e.g. `web` or `api`)
- `$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` is empty for branches with no associated open MRs (duh), but contains up to 4 MR names in case it's used as a source branch in open MRs. This envar is only present in branch and MR pipelines.

This, combined with proper `rules` order, explains the workflow rules described above.

Feel free to add the following job to your pipeline to demonstrate the interaction of predefined CI variables:

```yaml
show-conditions:
  stage: .pre
  cache: []
  script:
    - echo "Branch = $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    - echo "MR source = $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME"
    - echo "MR target = $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME"
    - echo "Source = $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE"
    - echo "Merge request is open = $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"
    - echo "Merge request = $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID"
```